# Tensorflow output layer should only have values between a specific range

Tags: python, range, tensorflow, output, layer

i am working with tensorflow and have following CNN (code below). My input layer is a 72x72 image and it outputs a 18x18 matrix because of the two maxpool layers.

now my question:
is it possible to define a range for the values in the output matrix (18x18)? so that the values are only between [0,1] ? because actually the output matrix should represent a density map. So i do not need values above 1.

my "groundtruth label" is a 18x18 matrix with values only between [0,1]. 
because my net is not trained yet, the loss is very high because the values in the output matrix are very high eg. 2379922. If i could provide a range for the output values, then the loss would be not that high in the beginning.

thank you for any help :-)

```
weights = {'W_conv1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([7, 7, 1, 32])),
           'W_conv2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([7, 7, 32, 32])),
           'W_conv3': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5, 5, 32, 64])),
           'W_conv4': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1, 1, 64, 1000])),
           'W_conv5': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1, 1, 1000, 400])),
           'W_conv6': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1, 1, 400, 1]))}

biases = {'b_conv1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([32])),
          'b_conv2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([32])),
          'b_conv3': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([64])),
          'b_conv4': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1000])),
          'b_conv5': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([400])),
          'b_conv6': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1]))}

#x = tf.reshape(x, shape=[-1, 28, 28, 1])
#x = tf.reshape(x, shape=[-1, 72, 72, 1])

conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(x, weights['W_conv1']) + biases['b_conv1'])
conv1 = maxpool2d(conv1)

conv2 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(conv1, weights['W_conv2']) + biases['b_conv2'])
conv2 = maxpool2d(conv2)

conv3 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(conv2, weights['W_conv3']) + biases['b_conv3'])

conv4 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(conv3, weights['W_conv4']) + biases['b_conv4'])

conv5 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(conv4, weights['W_conv5']) + biases['b_conv5'])

conv6 = conv2d(conv5, weights['W_conv6']) + biases['b_conv6']

return conv6
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the values in your ground truth table represent a probability distribution.You could use the [softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/api_docs/python/nn.html#softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits) as your loss function, as explained in this [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/tutorials/mnist/pros/index.html#build-a-softmax-regression-model) in the official documentation. It would essentially take the output from the final layer, apply softmax to calculate the probabilities (thus bringing down the values in the range of 0 to 1) and then calculate the loss against the actual values.

However, if the values in the ground truth table do not represent an actual probability distribution, then you could either try to normalize the output values, or apply the `sigmoid` function in the output layer.

Comment: Is this the update for the linked tutorial? https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits